# Does anybody have any good premade creatures from the void I can use?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

I have been looking for creatures from the void (the plane) and haven't found any premade creatures, or anything in the books. Does anybody have any ideas where I can find creatures from the void? I'm looking for things like soul-eaters and void lords. The best description of the void that I found is [this 4e homebrew article](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Void,_The_%284e_Environment%29).

Clarification: No, I am looking for things similar. I kind of figured out that 3 didn't have a void, but I would like to use the 4e void in my 3e game, so I want creatures that can fit inside of it. I have read that I should use the outside template on creatures to make them 'void creatures'. Does anybody have an example of a creature with an outside template on it? (Like an outside owlbear?)

I also found some things from the oriental adventures on the void; can anybody explain if that void is like the 4e version in the link above?

Also, I just found this: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/The_Void_(3.5e_Environment)

Comment: To clarify, you're asking for official 3.5 stats on creatures from homebrew location designed for Fourth Edition?

Comment: The Void did not exist in 3e, and therefore there will not be any official creatures.

Comment: @KRyan I'm pretty sure the Void doesn't exist in 4e either--it's not the Far Realm--but either edition might have creature stats that are similar to the Void creatures that Sage is looking for. That's why we need him to clarify if he's only looking for officially published stat blocks that are explicitly for "void creatures." (And 3e's *Oriental Adventures* does have something called the Void.)

Comment: @BESW If memory serves, the Void from 3e's Oriental Adventures is one of the five elements, along fire, water, air and earth, not a plane.

Comment: VTC as unclear until we can get some clarification and confirmation about what this void is (or *which* void it is) and, hopefully, which source is the one that defined that particular void (if there is one).

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I'm not sure that we'll ever get something clearer than "I would like to use the 4e void in my 3e game".

Comment: About Oriental Adventures, the Void they refer to there is an elemental plane/type of existence that I am fairly sure is vastly different to the 4e version if the 4e version is being compared to the Far Realms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know some people are not fans of WOTC Articles, but I did find this [Monster Mayhem Article on "Dwellers of the Void"](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mm/20031219a). Additionally, I vague remember a creature called "Shadow of the Void" ( [online here](http://www.charles-reace.com/Hobbies/DnD_Monster_DB/index.php?id=70) ) though I cannot recall what book it is from ( the link sounds right, but I don't have my collection on hand to reference it).

It is definitely something from Orient Adventures, so that source book may have more examples.

Comment: Shadow of the Void is from the Epic Level handbook.